# How can I format a non date value as a date value

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, types, formatting

I am creating a custom type `DateOnly` which is effectively a `DateTime` with the Time portion removed.

I have run into a small problem where I want to format the Value of my new type like a date:

```
Dim startDate As New DateOnly(2012, 1, 2)
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:ddd}", startDate))
```

This outputs: `02/01/2012`, I want to be able to format this to be `Mon`

Note: I haven't included any of my code for the `DateOnly` type (to keep things simple) but I can add it if requested

Comment: I guess the format string "ddd" (or any other format string for Date) would work only on a DateTime object. You might want to try subclassing your new DateOnly class from DateTime

Comment: uhh, convert it to a `DateTime` if you want to use the `DateTime` formatting codes.

Comment: but, datetime.date already returns only the date part.. and when you refer to mon, you are thinking monday? you want to format all the date as monday?

Comment: Any reason why you're not just using dtVariable.Date?

Comment: @ingo - the reason why is because I need to compare dates all the time, if I forget to add `.Date` when doing this and one of them has a time component the compare returns False even though the date component is the same - it is just mistake proofing really

Comment: NO need to worry about it, if every time you add a date time variable is wrapped around a property that just throw out the time part. Why reinvent the wheel?? We all have the same problem ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to answer my own problem by implementing `IFormattable` in my custom type:

```
Public Overloads Function ToString(fmt As String, provider As IFormatProvider) As String Implements IFormattable.ToString
    Return String.Format("{0:" + fmt + "}", _dateValue)
End Function
```

This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

works for me (C#):

```
  DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, 1, 2);
  var dateString = String.Format("{0:ddd}", date); //Mon
```

anyway what about the below:

```
 DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, 1, 2);
 var dayName= date.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

if `DateOnly` is a DateTime you can do :

```
DateOnly.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

for all the culture

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int) 
                System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek];
```

more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx

Comment: He's not using DateTime, he has his own class which he is trying to apply his format to named DateOnly.

Comment: he does not need his own class to achieve that. Anyway if his own class returns a DateTime object he can still use .DayOfWeek.ToString();

Comment: Your first code uses `DateTime` I am using a custom Type 'DateOnly', `DayOfWeek.ToString` returns `Monday` and is not the same as `ddd` which returns `Mon`

Comment: you don't need your custom datetime for that. 
You can truncate the string to get only the first 3 chars

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso - can you be sure that `ddd` is the same as `DayOfWeek.SubString(0,3)` for all languages / cultures?

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you need to get the day name against a date you better use the framework instead of creating your own class